# Unable to set sourceDir in php core/console composer correctly

Tags: php

The directory I have installed composer is in `/home/salman/styleguide` and I am trying to set the `sourceDir` of php core/console as: `php core/console --config --set sourceDir="/home/salman/service/templates/"`

But for some reason when I run `php core/console --config --list` the `sourceDir` is getting set as : `/home/salman/styleguide/home/salman/service/templates/`

How do I solve this problem and set my sourceDir in `php core/console` correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the `sourceDir` gets appeneded with the `baseDir`. So if I use a relative directory like `../../templates` it works fine.